# Who killed the frog?

Tags: riddle, logical-deduction, puzzle-creation

**There was one frog, mistakenly fallen into a pan full of boiling water**.

> No animals were harmed in the making of this question

Biologically, frog has tendency to change the temperature of his/her skin according to the external temperature.

So, the frog adjusted it's body temperature according to the boiling water.

Water temperature rises, again the frog changes it's body temperature.

Gradually, the water temperature became so high that it couldn't tolerate it anymore.

So, it started doing the only thing it could do- Jump from the pan.

But tragedy happens, the frog died.

**Now, the question is- who killed the frog?**

Hint

> Related to life

Comment: Initially you say that the frog fell into a pan of boiling water, but later that the temperature is rising presumably towards boiling point- perhaps the start should say a pan full of water _on the boil_ ?

Comment: Consider editing your question before it can be declared as of **too broad** to answer!

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay But its answer lies in the question itself

Comment: Still there can be many answers apart from the answer you are looking for.

Comment: This is too broad even for a try. How many ways can you think of killing a frog? Each one will qualify as an answer,

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like a Lateral Thinking puzzle (a Yes/No game.) Is it one? What I mean: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Situation_puzzle

Comment: I don't see any `riddle` (or any puzzle) here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one that killed the frog is

> the frog

because

> it was adjusting its body temperature to be slightly above the temperature of the surroundings. Doing this constantly caused the temperature of the water to rise to the point that it was unbearable.

Comment: your is answer is right but your explation need more work

Comment: Well, if you accepted the answer anyway, why not share what the desire explanation was/is?

Answer (score 1):

**Who?**

> Nature,Fate,Karma and what else....

**How?**

> The frog adjusted his body temperature to that of boiling water. On jumping out of pan, his body instantly cooled to room temperature and he couldn't adapt to this as quick. And he died.

Comment: No ,his body can adapt quick changes in temprature and when he fall again into the pan he adapted the hot temprature too

Comment: @rudra I will update the answer as I think of something else. Is it specifically a 'who' or it can be a 'what'?

Answer (score 1):

It is

> the person who is boiling the water(though there is a frog in the pan) or the settings/set up made for boiling water killed the frog.

Also, it can be

> post jumping it landed in the source of heat instead of a safe place.

Answer (score 1):

> It. (Pennywise, or whatever Its name is.)

explanation:

> The first hint comes from the way the word "its" is misspelled as " it's". Or rather, the word is not misspelled at all, because it refers to someone named "It". This also matches with rudra's insistence that the answer is in the question. When the frog boils the water to a high enough temperature, It (the clown!) tries to jump out of the pot, accidentally crushing the frog(or maybe just dropping the frog into the fire.)

Answer (score 0):

Well. This is a halfhearted attempt.

> The Pan Is closed.(more appropriately, you have put a lid on the pan). Biologists claim that on increasing the temperature of the water suddenly the frog would jump out **if it has the means to do so**. However, the cruel guy who put the frog in the boiling water in the first place also put a lid on the pan. Thus, the frog jumped but couldn't get out of the pan and hence, died. Sad.

EDIT: Another half hearted attempt.

> Who killed the frog? **The frog itself**. Because the water was too hot, it couldn't jump out quickly enough and died. (You could also plug in some morality lessons here.. But I digress)